# Data manipulation with Lodash chaining or functional JS challenge

Tags: javascript, lodash, data-manipulation

I have a set of data

```
const allNumbers = [
    { type: "smallNumbers", numbers: [1, 2, 3] },
    { type: "bigNumbers", numbers: [4, 5, 6] }
];
```

that needs to be molded into

```
[[1], [2], [3], [4, 5, 6]]
```

where numbers in objects of type `smallNumbers` are each individually wrapped in an array, and numbers in objects of type `bigNumbers` are simply left as is.

How would I do this with Lodash chaining (if possible) or plain functional JS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`_.flatMap()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#flatMap) to iterate the objects, and use [`_.chunks()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#chunk) (default chunk size is 1) to split `smallNumbers` to subarrays:

```js
const allNumbers = [
  { type: "smallNumbers", numbers: [1, 2, 3] },
  { type: "bigNumbers", numbers: [4, 5, 6] }
];

const result = _.flatMap(allNumbers, ({ type, numbers }) => 
  _.eq(type, 'smallNumbers') ? _.chunk(numbers) : [numbers]
);

console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```